# Azure IoT Hub SAS Key Manual Generation via Connection string with HMAC encryption via Forge js lib

Tags: angular, security, ionic2, hmac, azure-iot-hub

Having trouble testing getting past 401 in azure-iot-hub with manual SAS key generation via connection string in a javascript (typescript) file using the forge javascript library.

Connection string looks is as follows: `HostName={resourceUri};SharedAccessKeyName={policyName};SharedAccessKey={key}"`

I break the string into a dictionary, calculate the expiration time myself (adding 3600 seconds), and go on to calculate the SAS key url params with the following functions:

```
// MSDN recommendation   
const encodeUriComponentStrict = (str) => {
      return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
        return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
      });
    }

function hmacHash(password, signingString) {
  const hmac = forge.hmac.create();
  console.log(`password`, password);
  hmac.start('sha256', forge.util.encode64(password));
  hmac.update(signingString);
  const digested = hmac.digest();
  return forge.util.encode64(digested.data);
}

/**
 * Creates a Sas key for an azure iot registry
 * @param hostName the azure iot resource uri
 * @param policy the shared access key name
 * @param key the shared access key
 * @param expiry int64 representation of expiration time
 */
const createSasKeyForRegistry = (hostName: string, policy: string,
    key: string, expiry: number) => {
    let sas : any = {
        _key: key,
        sr: hostName,
        se: expiry,
        skn: encodeUriComponentStrict(policy),
    };
  sas.sig = encodeUriComponentStrict(hmacHash(sas._key, stringToSign(sas.sr, sas.se)));

  return sas;
}
```

Here's an example resource `PUT` IoT device endpoint I can see in the console:
`https://{my-resource-uri}.net/devices/807417987db61b41ZX1F239P3Q?api-version=2016-11-14`

I can see that the `Authorization` header is appended in the usual SAS key format:

`"SharedAccessSignature sr={resource-uri}&sig=koNqIJF56tzzBpqWYp4tRvxeWIJEHSLugA2O2weELZ4%3D&se=1492307707&skn=iothubowner"`.

Despite all this, I'm still getting an 401... Been at it for a couple hours now trying all sorts of things without any success. Wondering if it has something to do with the hmac encryption function?  Any forge folks out there that can verify the code?  For those interested, I'm in an ionic 2 application (based on angular 2) and using angular 2's http class to perform the request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I haven't had 50 reputation now, I cannot post this as a comment.

Did you decode the SharedAccessKey with base64?

I'm not familiar with Forge, but here's what I did with CryptoJS

https://github.com/azure-iothub/device-management/blob/master/main.js#L117

The connectionInfo is gotten from connection string with getInfoFromConnectionString method

https://github.com/azure-iothub/device-management/blob/master/main.js#L74

I hope this can help.

Comment: Definitely was that.  Thanks for the help!